# Docker network configuration with GigE camera interface

Tags: docker, docker-network, alliedvision, vimba-sdk

I'm trying to containerize a program that uses the [Vimba SDK](https://www.alliedvision.com/en/products/vimba-sdk/) to control a GigE camera, which is connected by Ethernet from a secondary network interface on the host system.

Vimba seems to want direct control over the camera network interface. For example, it brings the interface up and configures its MTU. It works to run the container with `--network host` to give it access to the `eth0` interface on the host.

However I was wondering if it would be possible to use Docker networking to:

1. Allow the hosts on the LAN to access a web service running in the container (i.e., `--publish 8080:8080/tcp`).
2. Give the Vimba SDK a network interface it can control.

My attempt was to create a bridge network called `net-1-lan` and a macvlan network called `net-2-cam`. (Aside: The names are because when a container is in multiple networks, the network whose name comes first lexicographically gets chosen as the default route.)

```
docker network create net-1-lan  # bridge network
docker network create \
    --driver macvlan \
    --opt parent=eth0 \
    --subnet=169.254.1.0/24 \
    net-2-cam
```

After I start my container in the bridge network, I use `docker network connect` to add the container to the macvlan network. However, the Vimba SDK does not detect the camera.

One thing I note, but am unsure is relevant, is that the container gets IP address 169.254.1.2 on the macvlan interface. When running in `--network host` mode, the interface claims 169.254.1.1.